# R Cluster With Above and below threshold

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I want to cluster my data with  3 clusters above the red line, middle part and below the 2nd red line. how can I use Kmeans in R to solve this problem? or how can I rotate the dimension of the data? thanks in advance

Image of my cluster according to question:

[image: Image of my cluster according to question]

data set image:

[image: data set image]

Comment: Do you have any labels that could help with this? Is there some variable that is connected to these 3 regions? Or did you select these regions purely subjectively becaseu that's where the majority of cases are?

Comment: I am doing this to identifying the  Hyper Methylation and Hypo Methylation CPG sites from methylation data.  data labels are  cpg sites and samples.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Do you have the labels to separate the data in the way you presented? What are cpg sites and samples? How can you use them for this task?

Comment: i have added the picture of dataset

Comment: OK so I assume you do not have the labels, since in the first picture you are showing two (I assume) linear combinations of your variables. Can you then manually input the labels of what is the lower and upper bound for the two combined dimensions for the middle cluster (something like dc2<0 & dc2>-4)? After that you could perform clustering with k=3 clusters and watch the magic.

Comment: As a side note, do you think clustering is the best tool? Maybe a KNN it could be helpful, having a defined areas/points.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am gonna start with your direction.